# How to validate input and output messages in proxy service against wsdl

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to validate input and output messages in proxy service against specific wsdl?

Have a situation, when proxy generates invalid output message, so i want to catch this inside my proxy just before responding to client.

Also i want to check if input message is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like SoapUI to validate scenario like this. You can generate a test using particular wsdl. And you can use tool like tcpmon to validate the message going between proxy and the particular endpoint.

As a example use one tcpmon listening to out port to the proxy and redirect it to the actual port.

You can find soapui from [1] and if your using wso2 ESB the tcpmon is available at /bin directory and you can start it using

```
sh wso2esb-4.5.0/bin/tcpmon.sh
```

By looking at the message passing through tcpmon you can validate the message going out from your proxy.

[1]. http://sourceforge.net/projects/loadui/files/latest/download?source=files

Comment: Yes, i know about SoapUI capabilities and use them widely. :) My question was about runtime validation.

Comment: Easily you can log the output message by using a log mediator. By that you can validate your output message. by logging it .

Comment: I want to do it automatically. For example - if input or output messages are not valid, i want message to be directed to faultSequence, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the payload of the wso2 esb proxy using the Validate mediator.

Example,

```
  <validate source="//xpath_of_element_to_validate">
    <schema key="local_entry_name_of_your_schema_file"/>
    <on-fail>
      *This part contains the code to handle validation failure*
    </on-fail>
  </validate>
```

This Validate mediator can be used anywhere in the proxy. To validate the request, use it as the first line and to validate the response, use it before the respond mediator

You can refer the below link for more details,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Validate+Mediator

Hope this helps!!
Thanks!!